# WhatsApp for business API integration using Cloud API

Tags: java, spring-boot, whatsapp-cloud-api

How can I integrate my WhatsApp for business (not using any 3rd party tools like Pabbly, WANotifier, etc.) to send a pdf document (Purchase Order details) to the customers without having to send a welcome text message and the customer not having to reply back with anything to receive the pdf document (Purchase Order details)?.

**Note: if this is not possible then how does MakeMyTrip and book my show works where in which when we book tickets or shows we receive a pdf file (booking details) without we in person initiating the conversation of asking the booking details.**

Went through the official MetaforDevelopers document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api
but couldn't find any solutions.

If somebody finds something out of the document link attached above related to my requirement, please let me know!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create a template first and then send the message using message template.
Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates for more info